# python: how to tell if file executed as import vs. main script?

Tags: python, import

I'm writing a python file `mylib.py`

I'd like mylib.py to do something based on `sys.argv` if it's being executed as a script. But if it's imported from some other script, I don't want it to do that.

How can I tell if my python file is being imported or it's a main script?

(I've seen how to do this before, but I forgot.)

Comment: You're not alone in this, by the way. The incantation is hard to remember at first and it's often considered a wart of the language.

Comment: Seems like there should be a `sys.isMain()` function to make this easier.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this was run as a main script
```

Here is the [documentation on `__main__`](http://docs.python.org/library/__main__.html#module-__main__).

Usually this code is placed at the bottom of a module, and one common way to keep your code clean is to create a `main()` function that does all of the work, and only call that function inside of the conditional.

Answer (score 5):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # goes here only when module is being executed directly
```

Packages also can contain `__main__` module, which is executed when you do `python -m foo` (or execute zipfile containing the package).

Answer (score 0):

By using (placing the statements you want to be executed only when the module is running as `main`, not imported)

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
        # this was run as a main script
```

Generally different statements have has to be placed in this '**if**' block like , module specific  **doctest** call or print statements.The thing is by default (when running as main) the '**`__name__`**' variable is set to "`__main__`", and otherwise (if **imported**) the `__name__` variable 'll get a different value, most probably the name of the module.

Comment: +1 since it's correct... but I already got a correct answer a year ago.

Comment: @JasonS saw it, but wanted to share my answer (matter of fact I've myself grasped the concept recently). Thanks